# Почему две строки не хотят выстраиваться в противоположные стороны и как это сделать?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Снизу дан код, который, по идеи, должен раздвинуть "Left text" и "right text" в противоположные стороны. Но почему-то они стоят вплотную друг к другу. Можете объяснить в чём проблема и помочь в решении этой лёгкой задачи.

```
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 left">
              <h3>Left Text</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-10 right">
              right text
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384- 
  q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не вижу такого кода.

Answer (score 1):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>Left Text</div>
  <div>right text</div>
</section>
```

Comment: а с bootstrap оно не должно разве само как-то их разделять без флексов, а с применением только бутстрап? Допустим в этом видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNgj6d9ntnM&t=260s на 7:53 работает всё хорошо с этими классами

Comment: Может и должно, не знаю. Не люблю и не использую его.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете bootstrap.

Сетка у bootstrap - 12 колонок, вы используете все 12 колонок. Поэтому они никак не буду раздвинуты, а будут идти в потоке друг за другом.

Если Вы хотите создать элемент `.row`, в котором будет 2 блока, находящихся на противоположных углах, Вам лучше воспользоваться `.flex`.

Если Вы хотите обойтись без `.flex`, Вам нужно создать "пустое" пространство между этими блоками, например таким кодом (но такой подход глуп, просто потому что есть `.flex`)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    some text
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    some right text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошо, видимо, без флексов тут никак не справится, спасибо

Comment: @Рома flex - прекрасная штука, главное - понять её прелести) успехов